# Getting console error for object return

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi i have to disable button if i get scenariosViewAll.collectionBookObject ={} array ,For this i am using function to return below is my code:

```
  <button" ng-disabled="scenariosViewAll.isSetDisable(scenariosViewAll.collectionBookObject)">Create Book from Collection</button>
```

and in controller my code is:

```
 function isSetDisable(obj) {
           return typeof(obj === 'Object') && Object.keys(obj).length === 0 ? true : false;
        }
```

getting console error as below and it is working properly, any wrong in my code.

```
lib.min.js:3762 TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at scenariosViewAllController.isSetDisable (app.min.js:29729)
    at fn (eval at compile (lib.min.js:3876), <anonymous>:4:415)
    at m.$digest (lib.min.js:3787)
    at m.$apply (lib.min.js:3790)
    at lib.min.js:3803
    at e (lib.min.js:3690)
    at lib.min.js:3693
```

Comment: `typeof(obj === 'Object')` will always return `"boolean"` which is truthy

Comment: @Andreas then what is the solution

Comment: Check the documentation on the [`typeof` __operator__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Comment: @SudhirMN use typeof(obj) instead of typeof(obj === "Object)

Comment: (typeof(obj )=== 'Object') instead of typeof(obj === 'Object')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function isSetDisable(obj) {
           return typeof(obj) === 'object' && Object.keys(obj).length === 0 ? true : false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change `Object` condition and add extra condition to handle possible `null` values;

```
 function isSetDisable(obj) {
           return obj != null && typeof(obj) == typeof({}) && Object.keys(obj).length === 0 ? true : false;
        }
```